# Disallow user to logout using a new browser tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm facing the following problem. In my web application, there is logout button. If user scroll-click on it, it opens in a new tab, the user is logged out, but still have the previous tab which destroys after clicking on anything.

I know, that many apps disallow user to logout into a new tab. Maybe there are other solutions, but I'm very new to front-end and have no idea.

Comment: why does logout open a new tab? Change that behavior and problem solved

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong allowing user to logout in a separate window. However, what you need to do on your server side is verify that the user is logged in before allowing them to access any cards.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using native href attribute to redirect user to a new page, 
it is impossible to prevent.

You can use some JS "hacks". 
An example could be:

1. create an anchor element with some js function binded
2. prevent default behaviour (working on event object)
3. make a custom ajax call pointing to the logout server controller
4. refresh the page when response comes

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunatelly I can't do that, so I can't mark your answer as solution. Up arrow for you :)